# CSS padding while retaining the defined size?

Tags: html, css, padding

According to the standard, adding padding to a HTML element in CSS will grow the element by the amount defined. For example:

```
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

will add 20 pixels to the .elem's sides, causing the *actual* width and height to be 140px total.

Since this is actually pretty impractical in web design (having to calculate and keep track of the resulting sizes), I was wondering if it was somehow possible to do the reverse instead. I set a padding, and the inner text area shrinks instead. So the element stays at 100*100px, has the padding of 20px inside it, and I don't have to worry about messing up my design while experimenting with the padding.

Is this possible? Perhaps through a language that compiles to CSS (haven't looked into that much)? And perhaps a more minor question: why does it work this way in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `box-sizing`:

```
elemSelector {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This value for the property declares that the declared size of the element will include the `border` and the `padding`.

References:

- [`box-sizing` at: 'CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS UI)'](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#box-sizing).
- [`box-sizing` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: Wow. CSS3 introduced exactly that? And it seems to be compatible across the board (in modern browsers, obviously). Thanks so much for making me aware of this. Will set your answer as accepted in 7 minutes. :)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

It is currently impossible to perform what you are after. You'll have to account for padding in total width before you attempt to define what your css 'width' value will be. For more information on this, see the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). This is the only method to guarantee correct sizing in all web-capable devices, CSS3 compatible and not.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know the CSS box model by heart, but just wished it worked differently. What I asked for does seem possible, though - David Thomas posted an answer with a CSS3 solution and after a quick test it seems to be doing exactly what I tried to explain.